# Styling and Formatting the ComboBox selected item to match the ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, combobox, string-formatting

I have bound a `ComboBox` to a list of `DateTime` values to select a start time for an event.  I am using an `ItemTemplate` to specify the formatting of the `DateTime` in the list.  I also want the user to be able to manually specify a start time *not* in the list, like `8:27 AM` or `9:30 PM`.

Wiring that up is not the issue; rather, I want the user to be presented with the same formatted `DateTime` as the list.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="StartTimeButton"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.StartTimes, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultStartTime}"
          IsEditable="True">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Label>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:hh:mm tt}'}" />
         </Label>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

### This results in:

[image: Editable Text Area is not formatted the same as the dropdown area.]

I have been unable to determine how to format the top `TextBlock` used by the `ComboBox` (when editing is enabled) to match the formatting of the dropdown area.

Comment: There should not be a `Label` in there.

Comment: @H.B. The `Label` provides padding and margins to make the list of items more pleasing to the eye.  The `TextBox` is inside the `Label` because it has a `Text` property and can be formatted with `StringFormat`.  

Getting rid of the `Label` made no difference in the face of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: `Labels` are *only* for labeling other things, this is abuse. If you want padding define a *Style*.

Comment: @H.B.  I agree.  However, despite this grievous error, the Label has nothing to do with the issue at hand.  Can we focus on _that_ please?

Comment: Why exactly do you think i posted that as a comment and not in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultra shorthand that gets you halfway there (you can drop the `DataTemplate`):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Times}"
          IsEditable="True" ItemStringFormat="hh:mm tt"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Hour"/>
```

The problem is, that `DateTime` has no property that outputs the time in that format. Personally, i would write a wrapper that has an internal `DateTime` and a property that facilitates formatting to string and parsing from it.

There does not appear to be a standard way of creating a new item form the entered text, so you might need to parse the `ComboBox.Text` manually in case a value is entered that is not in the list.

Comment: Yeah, I fully expect to have to do some manual parsing - but for the life of me I can't get the face of the ComboBox to display a selected DateTime the same way as the list.  I even tried [creating a custom template selector](http://wpf.2000things.com/2014/02/19/1012-using-a-different-data-template-for-the-face-of-a-combobox/) and I can't get that to work either.

Comment: `TextSearch.TextPath` does that if the property it's pointed to returns the correct string.